# Difficulty to clean from najasah for salah

Tags: sharia

Hello I am a muslim and I have urine incontinence + difficulty cleaning my anus from impurities. I use water, soap, toilet paper but there are still impurities when I check. Sometimes I stay more than 30 or 40 minutes in the toilet just to clean myself from the impurities. I tried doing everything to clean myself correctly but it still doesn't work. So it becomes a huge effort to pray. How do I do this ? Is there a special rule for people like me who do all their effort to clean themselves but still aren't clean ? Jazakumu Allah khair.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I ask Allah The All Mighty to cure you from this and make it easy on you. Second, I would advice you to check with a doctor and see if there's any treatment for this or not, and what actions the doctor might recommend, whether it's medicine or diet. Moreover, this most probably stems form overthinking and insinuation (waswasa), so I'd recommend you try your best in cleaning, then head to prayer without overthinking as you've done what you're supposed to do with your best effort, and Allah knows best. I would also suggest you read what scholars have said regarding people who have incontrollable gasses, and how to deal with it.